# Como realizar estas consultas en SQLITE3

Tags: insert, update, sqlite3, delete

quiero hacer consultas de insercion, actualizacion y borrado en estas tres tablas con select lo hago utilizando join de la sig forma:

```
SELECT * 
FROM preceptores 
    JOIN barrio ON preceptores.id = barrio.id 
    JOIN localidad ON barrio.id = localidad.id 
    WHERE preceptores.id = 12;
```

Me gustaría saber si se hace de forma similar con insert, update y delete y si me pueden dar un ejemplo de cada uno utilizando solo dos tablas para ver como se hace... les agradecere la ayuda ya que solo encontre algo asi con mysql con la clausula update y los join se ubican distinto a como se ubican en select... gracias

```
id  usuario  clave      conf_clave  nombre  apellido  dni       fecha       telefono  mail                id_ba
--  -------  ---------  ----------  ------  --------  --------  ----------  --------  ------------------  -----
10  mario11  Mario1122  Mario1122   mario   salas     25123987                                                 
11  susy33   Susy3322   Susy3322    susana  mendez    25369002  10/05/1976                                     
12  lucas8   Lucas888   Lucas888    lucas   sosa      20110114                        lucass@hotmail.com       
13  lucho00  Lucho0011  Lucho0011   luis    santos    20112233                        lucho@gmail.com          
14  diego11  Diego2211  Diego2211   diego   manso     21221112
```

---

```
id  calle            barrio        id_loc
--  ---------------  ------------  ------
1   Brasil 45        Cementerio          
2   San Martin 345   Centro              
3   Belgrano 567     Los Pinares         
4   Rosario 55       Las Rosas           
7   olmos 44         alamos              
8   laprida 221      mainero             
9   marmol 33        las lilas           
10  costa 33         barrio costa        
11  las abelias 123  las flores          
12  bolivia 44       centro              
13  barcelona 44     sur                 
14
```

---

```
id  localidad    CP   
--  -----------  -----
1   Bell Ville   2550 
2   Morrison     2568 
3   J Posse      2553 
4   Bell Ville   2550 
6   morrison     2568 
7   bell ville   2550 
8   ballesteros  2572 
9   bell ville   2550 
10  j posse           
11  morrison          
12  ballesteros       
13                    
14  men bell     55111
```

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuál es el problema en concreto? ¿Qué has investigado / intentado y qué dificultades tienes con el código que has intentado o qué no has entendido de lo que investigaste? Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.

Comment: sql es un solo lenguaje.. puede que el motor tenga alguna particularidad, pero en general las cosas se escriben igual en todos los motores...

Comment: Si he encontrado una forma de hacerlo en mysql asi es que voy a intentar con eso, saludos y gracias